# Sharing variable between nodes in a device tree

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, device-tree, petalinux

I'm trying to find a way to accesses, from node_1, a variable in node_0 (see code below) in this device-tree:

```
/ {
    amba_pl: amba_pl@0 {
      node_0: node@a8000000 {
         node_id = <0x0>;
         node0State = <0x0>;
      };
   };

      node_1: node@a9000000 {
         node1State = <node_0's node0State>;
      };
   };
};
```

The primary goal is to be able to share a state between kernel modules.  I'm aware that I can EXPORT_SYMBOL(variable) in the writing node and then extern *variable in the reading node, but wanted to see if I could accomplish this in the device-tree itself.  node_0 would always be the only node to set the nodeState, and node_1 would only read.  Is this possible?

Comment: Suddenly I know that it’s easy in ACPI, but in DT probably you can use C preprocessing. I am not sure if it is possible at run time (again ACPI can do it all).

Answer (score 0):

You can store a phandle referring to the node containing `node0state`:

```dts
/ {
    amba_pl: amba_pl@0 {
      node_0: node@a8000000 {
         node_id = <0x0>;
         node0State = <0x0>;
      };
   };

      node_1: node@a9000000 {
         stateNode = <&node_0>;
      };
   };
};
```

In the driver code, if `struct device_node *mynode;` refers to the `node_1` node, the `node0state` property of the other node referred to by the `stateNode` phandle property can be accessed as follows:

```c
    int rc = 0;
    struct device_node *np;
    u32 node0state;

    np = of_parse_phandle(mynode, "stateNode", 0);
    if (!np) {
        // error node not found
        rc = -ENXIO;
        goto error1;
    }
    
    // Do whatever is needed to read "node0state".  Here is an example.
    rc = of_property_read_u32(np, "node0state", &node0state);
    if (rc) {
        // error
        of_node_put(np);  // decrement reference to the node
        goto error2;
    }

    // Finished with the node.
    of_node_put(np);  // decrement reference to the node
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  So is stateNode modifiable by node_1?  Also, is node0State modifiable by node_0?  I've been using of_property_read_u32() to get the field value, but it looks like there isn't a of_property_write_u32() in of.h

Comment: @plasmaphase, You can’t write to OF — it’s only for getting data. But you may modify it with overlays.